# Changing a styled-component style based on state at the top of app

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

So I have a simple navbar that when hits a certain media query it turns into a hamburger, and when I click on hamburger-icon, I want the new navbar element slide over.  Here is how I have it setup.

### Layout Component

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleSidebar = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar toggleSidebar={toggleSidebar} />
      <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} toggleSidebar={toggleSidebar}/>
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

### Sidebar Component

```
const SidebarAside = styled.aside`
  background: ${props => props.theme.grey10};
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ${props => props.theme.transition};
  transform: translateX(-100%);

  ${props =>
    props.showsidebar && css`
      opacity: 1;
      tranform: translateX(0);
    `
  }
`
const CloseButton = styled.button`
  position: absolute;
  right: 4.75%;
  top: 2.75%;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: ${props => props.theme.redDark};
  cursor: pointer;
`
const Sidebar = ({isOpen, toggleSidebar,}) => {
  return (
    <SidebarAside showsidebar={isOpen}>
      <CloseButton onClick={toggleSidebar}>
        <FaTimes />
      </CloseButton>
    </SidebarAside>
  )
}
```

First time using styled-components, and not totally sure what my angle for this should be.

Comment: I don't understand your goal. Can you share more details about what you want to get?

Comment: Ultimately on smaller devices when the "CloseButton" component is clicked it will use the "Sidebar" component as the face of the view.  I am using useState to control, it but I am unfamiliar how this would happen with styled-components

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I figured it out, with just changing the syntax in the styled component to...

#### Sidebar Styled Component

```
 opacity: ${props => props.showsidebar ? '1' : '0'};
 transform: ${props => props.showsidebar ? 'translateX(0)' : 'translateX(-100%)'};
`
const Sidebar = ({isOpen, toggleSidebar,}) => {
  return (
    <SidebarAside showsidebar={isOpen}>
      <CloseButton onClick={toggleSidebar}>
        <FaTimes />
      </CloseButton>
    </SideBarAside>
```